# subtract two columns from different tables and update the inventory

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update the product quantity in store inventory table based on quantity sold in SALELINE table

so, I want to subtract QTYONHAND from Store_inv and QTYSOLD from SALELINE table for each product which has a Product_id

Store_inv and SALELINE both has a Product_id as (FK)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't clear what data you have in table.Based on your question assumption
  I posted below query.First Subtract qty from two tables using subquery than update inventory table

```
UPDATE store_inventory SET product_quantity = A.SubQty
FROM 
(
   SELECT ( QTYONHAND - QTYSOLD ) SubQty,SALELINE.Product_id AS Product_id
   FROM Store_inv
   JOIN SALELINE ON Store_inv.Product_id = SALELINE.Product_id
) A 
WHERE A.Product_id = store_inventory.Product_id
```

Comment: store_inventory table has: product_id QTY

SALELINE table has: SALE_Number SALE_date product_id QTYsold Total

Product table has: product_id product_name product_price

I want to update the QTY in store_inventory table after sale transaction for each product by subtracting Quantity in store_inventory table and Quantity sold in SALELINE table

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codeproject.com/questions/555388/howplustoplussubtractplustwoplusvaluesplusinplussq

refer this page you will get some idea

Comment: When posting link references you need to include enough context from the linked page that your response will remain relevant even if the linked source becomes unavailable.

Comment: Thank u sentinel for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE SALELINE s
INNER JOIN store_inv si ON s.product_id = si.product_id
SET s.product_quantity = (si.QTYONHAND-s.QTYSOLD)
```

Comment: In oracle above syntax can work please try the edited query.